# How would I 'wrap' an object and replace all of the functions in it?

Tags: javascript, function, object, wrapper

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
var obj = {
  something: 1,
  someFunction: function () {
    return 'hello';
  }
};

wrap(obj).someFunction('hello'); // this should be different from obj.someFunction defined above
wrap(obj).something = 2; // this should still work
```

Basically, I want to 'wrap' an object and replace all the functions in it with something else.

Here's how I've defined the `wrap` function:

```
function hello (v) {
  return 'Hello ' + v;
}

function wrap (oldObj) {
  var newObj = {};

  for (var k in oldObj)
    Object.defineProperty(newObj, k, {
      get: function () {
        if (typeof oldObj[k] === 'function')
          return hello;
        return oldObj[k];
      },
      set: function (val) {
        oldObj[k] = val;
      }
    });

  return newObj;
}
```

(`hello` is just an example replacement function)

When I try to use this, everything in `obj` gets replaced with a function (i.e even `obj.something`, which was set to 1, is replaced with a function). I can't seem to find any issues with this code. I've tried debugging it and haven't found the issue yet.

What might be the issue? How else can I solve this problem?

**Edit 1**: I don't want to replace functions in the object itself, I want to create an entirely new object.

Comment: the answer right there: "create an closure to maintain function name"

Comment: I don't want to replace functions in the object that I'm wrapping, I want to create an entirely new object.

Comment: There's hardly a difference whether you create your setters on the original or a new object, what you were missing is the closure.

Comment: the problem is by the time it got set, it is highly unlikely that your k iteration is the same as your property, extract the property creation to it's own methods, like eg: `function(source, target, property) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, property, {
            get: function() {
                return source[property];
            },
            set: function(val) {
                source[property] = val;
            }
        });
    };` and use this one inside your iteration (call `funcProper(oldObj, newObj, k)`), this will make sure your property is correctly extracted

Comment: more info: http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/drfjhkkk/